# Spy on a field assignment using Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, field, spy

How could I spy on a field assignment using Jasmine?

E.g. I have the object under test:

```
const testObj = {
    testObjField: null,
    testObjFunc: function() { this.testObjField = "foo"; }
}
```

Now I want to assert that the `testObj.testObjFunc` will assign the `"foo"` to the `testObj.testObjField`. How should I proceed?

Here is what I tried:

```
  //arrange
  const testObj = {
    testObjField: null,
    testObjFunc: function () {
      this.testObjField = 'foo';
    }
  };

  const testObjTestObjFieldSpy = spyOnProperty(testObj, 'testObjField', 'set');

  //act
  testObj.testObjFunc();

  //assert
  expect(testObjTestObjFieldSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo');
```

But I am getting the error:

> Error:  : Property testObjField does not have access type set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spy on fields, only on methods.

I would do this:

```
//arrange
  let testObj = {
    testObjField: null,
    testObjFunc: function () {
      this.testObjField = 'foo';
    }
  };

  // !! Get a copy of the original
  const originalTestObj = { ...testObj };

  //act
  testObj.testObjFunc();

  //assert
  expect(testObj.testObjField).toBe('foo');
  
  // !! Reset testObj to what it was if that is required
  testObj = { ...originalTestObj };
```